# How strict C/C++ compilers about operator precedence/evaluation?

Tags: c++, c, operators, logical-operators

This question is been on my mind for a while so time to let it out and see what what you guys you have to say about it.

In C/C++ the operator precedence is defined by the C specification but as with everything there may be backdoors or unknown / not well known things that the compilers may employ under the name of 'optimization' which will mess up your application in the end.

Take this simple example :

```
bool CheckStringPtr(const char* textData)
{
    return (!textData || textData[0]==(char)0);
}
```

In this case I test if the pointer is null *then* I check the first char is zero, essentially this is a test for a zero length string. Logically the 2 operations are exchangeable but if that would happen in some cases it would crash with since it's trying to read a non-existent memory address.

So the question is : is there *anything* that enforces the order of how operators/functions are executed, I know the safest way is to use 2 IFs below each other but this way should be the same **assuming** that the evaluation order of the operators never ever change.
So are compilers forced by the C/C++ specification to not change the order of evaluation or are they sometimes allowed to change the order, like it depends on compiler parameters, optimizations especially?

Comment: Is there anything? Yes, the language standard.

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx on order of operations and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azk8zbxd.aspx on sequence points.  It is a bit more accessible than the C standard.  also see https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP10-C.+Do+not+depend+on+the+order+of+evaluation+of+subexpressions+or+the+order+in+which+side+effects+take+place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C and C++ standards explicitly support short-circuit evaluation, and thus require the left-hand operand of the `&&`, `||`, or `?` operator to be evaluated before the right-hand side.

Other "sequence points" include the comma operator (not to be confused with commas separating function arguments as in `f(a, b)`), the end of a statement (`;`), and between the evaluation of a function's arguments and the call to the function.

But for the most part, order of evaluation (not to be confused with precedence) is implementation defined.  So, for example, don't depend on `f` to be called first in an expression like `f(x) + g(y)`.

Comment: This is what I thought, but the question is more about can you enforce the compiler or somehow predict how the compiler will evaluate an expression?

Comment: @DrakkLord: `first_expr = a + b; second_expr = c + d; result = first_expr * second_expr;`. Voilà, sequenced.

Comment: @rici - There is no guarantee that `first_expr =` happens before `second_expr = `. Optimizers are free to reorder those (unless you declared things `volatile`). The only thing that has to happen is that both have to be calculated before `result`

Comment: @MarkLakata: In that case, true. But if there is any way the order of evaluation is observable, the ';' must be obeyed. 1.9p14 "Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated." So if the evaluation of `a` or `b` had a side-effect observable in the evaluation of `c` or `d`, strict ordering would be required.

Answer (score 11):

First note that *precedence* and *evaluation order* are two different (largely unrelated) concepts.

> So are compilers forced by the C/C++ specification to not change the order of evaluation?

The compiler **must** produce behaviour that is consistent with the behaviour guaranteed by the C language standard.  It is free to change e.g. the order of evaluation so long as the overall observed behaviour is unchanged.

> Logically the 2 operations are exchangeable but if that would happen in some cases it would crash

`||` and `&&` are defined to have [*short-circuit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) semantics; they may not be interchanged.